AzureMonitorからCPU使用率の取得時 AttributeError: 'ServicePrincipalCredentials' object has no attribute 'get_token'
Python 3.8を使ってAzureリソースのCPU使用率を取得し、Zabbixで監視を行う事を考えております。
元々はPython 2.7向けのソースコードをPython 3.8のサンプルに合わせて修正を行いました。
サンプルを見つつ、修正をしましたが以下のエラーが残った状態となっています。
修正箇所の検討が付かず困っております。解決の方法が教えて頂けないでしょうか。
OS: Redhat 8.9を使用しています。
エラー内容：
File "/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/az_mngi_monitor.py", line 54, in <module>
metrics_data = client.metrics.list(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 94, in wrapper_use_tracer
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/mgmt/monitor/v2021_05_01/operations/_metrics_operations.py", line 801, in list
pipeline_response: PipelineResponse = self._client._pipeline.run( # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 229, in run
return first_node.send(pipeline_request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 86, in send
response = self.next.send(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 86, in send
response = self.next.send(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 86, in send
response = self.next.send(request)
[Previous line repeated 2 more times]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/mgmt/core/policies/_base.py", line 46, in send
response = self.next.send(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_redirect.py", line 197, in send
response = self.next.send(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_retry.py", line 532, in send
response = self.next.send(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_authentication.py", line 124, in send
self.on_request(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_authentication.py", line 99, in on_request
self._token = self._credential.get_token(*self._scopes)
AttributeError: 'ServicePrincipalCredentials' object has no attribute 'get_token'"

ソースコード
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
import sys
import datetime
from azure.monitor.query import MetricsQueryClient
from azure.mgmt.monitor import MonitorManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
#from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

import os
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "10.20.1.1:8080"
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "10.20.1.1:8080"
os.environ["https_proxy"] = "10.20.1.1:8080"
os.environ["http_proxy"] = "10.20.1.1:8080"

args = sys.argv
resource_group_name = args[1]  # Azure Resource Group name
rs_name = args[2]  # Azure SQL Managed Instance name
mtrx_name = args[3]  # Azure SQL Managed Instance Monitoring metric name
subscription_id = args[4]  # Subscription-ID

agr_type = 'Average'

resource_id = (
    f"subscriptions/{subscription_id}/"
    f"resourceGroups/{resource_group_name}/"
    f"providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/{rs_name}"
)

#create client
TENANT_ID = 'XXXXX'
CLIENT = 'XXXXX'
KEY = 'XXXXX'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = CLIENT,
    secret = KEY,
    tenant = TENANT_ID
)

#client = ComputeManagementClient(
client = MonitorManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)

nowtm = datetime.datetime.now()
justnowt = nowtm - datetime.timedelta(hours=9)
justnowt = justnowt - datetime.timedelta(minutes=4)
oneminbef = justnowt - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

#metrics_data = client.query(
metrics_data = client.metrics.list(
    resource_id,
    metric_names=mtrx_name,
    start_time=oneminbef,
    end_time=justnowt,
    interval='PT1M',
    aggregation=agr_type
)

for item in metrics_data:
    for timeserie in item.timeseries:
        for data in timeserie.data:
            print(format(data.average))

